# Iterate over ConcurrentHashMap while deleting entries

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrenthashmap

I want to periodically iterate over a `ConcurrentHashMap` while removing entries, like this:

```
for (Iterator<Entry<Integer, Integer>> iter = map.entrySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = iter.next();
    // do something
    iter.remove();
}
```

The problem is that another thread may be updating or modifying values while I'm iterating. If that happens, those updates can be lost forever, because my thread only sees stale values while iterating, but the `remove()` will delete the live entry.

After some consideration, I came up with this workaround:

```
map.forEach((key, value) -> {
    // delete if value is up to date, otherwise leave for next round
    if (map.remove(key, value)) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

One problem with this is that it won't catch modifications to mutable values that don't implement `equals()` (such as `AtomicInteger`). Is there a better way to safely remove with concurrent modifications?

Comment: Why not remove the entry before doing any work.

Comment: @ClaudioCorsi that won't change the fact that I'm seeing a stale version of a deleted entry.

Comment: The problem is that you need to be able to know what has been updated since you've started iterating through the map.  Even if you can know which objects have been updated.  It is still possible that another thread has a reference to a object that has been processed but that object has not been updated.  Is that object going to be added back or is it just being updated? Should this object generate another callback?

Comment: Are the entries short lived or long lived?  If they are short lived then you could consider using a weakreference as the value and then just process the reference queue.

Comment: @ClaudioCorsi I'm talking about updates that are visible to the map, e.g. `put()`, `merge()`, `compute()` etc.

Comment: Are the updates to the values an accumulation of the prior data?

Comment: The concurrent containers do not provide a callback mechanism that informs a thread of changes.  This is something that you would have to implement yourself.  Even then, it would be complex since you'd need to know if the updated value was processed or not and that just adds another layer of complexity.  It would almost be better to lock out all access to the map until you've completed you purge of the data.

Comment: Just to add few points, Iterator returned by ConcurrentHashMap is Fail-Safe Iterator. Javadoc says : Iterators and Enumerations return elements reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at or since the creation of the iterator/enumeration. They do not throw ConcurrentModificationException. However, iterators are designed to be used by only one thread at a time.

Comment: how many objects (max.) can your map contain?

Comment: @dit it's technically undefined. Why?

Comment: what about `CopyOnWriteList`?

Comment: Do (or can) your mutable value objects have `volatile` fields (so changes to their values are "seen" by all threads)?

Comment: @Bohemian, possibly, but the problem has nothing to do with visibility. It's a simple race condition.

Comment: @shmosel race conditions are easily handled with a `ConcurrentHashMap`. I'm asking about mutability because if they are thread friendly, the answer is quite simple.

Comment: @shmosel to get a solution, you must either make your values immutable (recommended) or provide a way to make a deep copy of them and implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` properly. Without one of those options, you can't do it IMHO.

Comment: @Bohemian, my example was `AtomicInteger`, which has a volatile value, and I guess would be considered thread friendly. But I don't think it matters, since `ConcurrentHashMap` reads and writes are always volatile.

Comment: Can I post a solution that assumes your values are threadsafe and have a proper `equals()` and `hashCode()` (like `AtomicInteger`)?

Comment: @Bohemian by all means. Though I'm beginning to think my workaround actually works fine.

Comment: Your workaround needs a tweak. Make a *copy* of the entry's value first, then test the *copied* value, then call `remove(key, copiedValue)` if the test passes. If another thread mutated the value between getting the value and removing it, you won't lose that update.

Comment: @Bohemian, that was DimitarDimitrov's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your workaround works but there is one potential scenario. If certain entries have constant updates map.remove(key,value) may never return true until updates are over.

If you use JDK8 here is my solution

```
for (Iterator<Entry<Integer, Integer>> iter = map.entrySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
    Entry<Integer, Integer> entry = iter.next();
    Map.compute(entry.getKey(), (k, v) -> f(v));
    //do something for prevValue
}
....
private Integer prevValue;

private Integer f(Integer v){
    prevValue = v;
    return null;
}
```

compute() will apply f(v) to the value and in our case assign the value to the global variable and remove the entry.

According to Javadoc it is atomic.

> Attempts to compute a mapping for the specified key and its current mapped value (or null if there is no current mapping). The entire method invocation is performed atomically. Some attempted update operations on this map by other threads may be blocked while computation is in progress, so the computation should be short and simple, and must not attempt to update any other mappings of this Map.

Comment: `compute()` will return null if `f()` returns null.

Comment: Also, it would be more straightforward to iterate over keys with your approach.

Answer (score 1):

Your workaround is actually pretty good. There are other facilities on top of which you can build a somewhat similar solution (e.g. using `computeIfPresent()` and tombstone values), but they have their own caveats and I have used them in slightly different use-cases.

As for using a type that doesn't implement `equals()` for the map values, you can use your own wrapper on top of the corresponding type. That's the most straightforward way to inject custom semantics for object equality into the atomic replace/remove operations provided by `ConcurrentMap`.

**Update**

Here's a sketch that shows how you can build on top of the `ConcurrentMap.remove(Object key, Object value)` API:

- Define a wrapper type on top of the mutable type you use for the values, also defining your custom `equals()` method building on top of the current mutable value.
- In your `BiConsumer` (the lambda you're passing to `forEach`), create a deep copy of the value (which is of type your new wrapper type) and perform your logic determining whether the value needs to be removed on the copy.
- If the value needs to be removed, call `remove(myKey, myValueCopy)`.

  - If there have been some concurrent changes while you were calculating whether the value needs to be removed, `remove(myKey, myValueCopy)` will return `false` (barring ABA problems, which are a separate topic).

Here's some code illustrating this:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Playground {

   private static class AtomicIntegerWrapper {
      private final AtomicInteger value;

      AtomicIntegerWrapper(int value) {
         this.value = new AtomicInteger(value);
      }

      public void set(int value) {
         this.value.set(value);
      }

      public int get() {
         return this.value.get();
      }

      @Override
      public boolean equals(Object obj) {
         if (this == obj) {
            return true;
         }
         if (!(obj instanceof AtomicIntegerWrapper)) {
            return false;
         }
         AtomicIntegerWrapper other = (AtomicIntegerWrapper) obj;
         if (other.value.get() == this.value.get()) {
            return true;
         }
         return false;
      }

      public static AtomicIntegerWrapper deepCopy(AtomicIntegerWrapper wrapper) {
         int wrapped = wrapper.get();
         return new AtomicIntegerWrapper(wrapped);
      }
   }

   private static final ConcurrentMap<Integer, AtomicIntegerWrapper> MAP
         = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

   private static final int NUM_THREADS = 3;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
         MAP.put(i, new AtomicIntegerWrapper(1));
      }

      Thread.sleep(1);

      for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i) {
         new Thread(() -> {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            while (!MAP.isEmpty()) {
               MAP.forEach((key, value) -> {
                  AtomicIntegerWrapper elem = MAP.get(key);
                  if (elem == null) {
                     System.out.println("Oops...");
                  } else if (elem.get() == 1986) {
                     elem.set(1);
                  } else if ((rnd.nextInt() & 128) == 0) {
                     elem.set(1986);
                  }
               });
            }
         }).start();
      }

      Thread.sleep(1);

      new Thread(() -> {
         Random rnd = new Random();
         while (!MAP.isEmpty()) {
            MAP.forEach((key, value) -> {
               AtomicIntegerWrapper elem =
                     AtomicIntegerWrapper.deepCopy(MAP.get(key));
               if (elem.get() == 1986) {
                  try {
                     Thread.sleep(10);
                  } catch (Exception e) {}
                  boolean replaced = MAP.remove(key, elem);
                  if (!replaced) {
                     System.out.println("Bailed out!");
                  } else {
                     System.out.println("Replaced!");
                  }
               }
            });
         }
      }).start();
   }
}
```

You'll see printouts of "Bailed out!", intermixed with "Replaced!" (removal was successful, as there were no concurrent updates that you care about) and the calculation will stop at some point.

- If you remove the custom `equals()` method and continue to use a copy, you'll see an endless stream of "Bailed out!", because the copy is never considered equal to the value in the map.
- If you don't use a copy, you won't see "Bailed out!" printed out, and you'll hit the problem you're explaining - values are removed regardless of concurrent changes.

Comment: Actually, I think my `equals()` point was a bit irrelevant. The problem will occur as long as the value is being mutated rather than replaced, because `remove()` is seeing the same reference. I guess the wrapper would work if we were willing to create a new one for each update.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I think this approach works fine for values being mutated. I'll update my answer to add a code sample illustrating the approach.

Comment: Your solution works, but my idea is a bit simpler for my requirements. I don't need to verify the current value before removing; I want to remove *any* value as long as I can see the latest version. So all I need to do is create a shallow wrapper copy while updating to avoid reference equality, and rely on the atomicity guarantees of `remove()` and update operations (via `compute()`, `merge()` etc.) to ensure that values can't be mutated after successful removal.

Comment: An additional benefit to my approach is that the wrapper doesn't need to implement `equals()`, and it can be completely generic because it doesn't require type-specific logic. For the purposes of my project, it's important that the values can be generic.

Comment: On second (fifth?) thought, I don't think mutable values are a problem at all. In fact, we could even use `Iterator.remove()` for mutable values, since they can't become stale, and the map's atomicity guarantees ensure that there won't be any modifications after removal. The only issue to begin with was immutable values, which can be replaced and thereby become stale. The solution to that problem is my workaround of calling `map.remove(Object, Object)` to make sure the value removed is the same one we're seeing.

Comment: Well, I can only answer the questions that you've posed, I cannot anticipate what are the actual issues that you're trying to solve without any additional context. And I think I've done the former :). The code sample that I've illustrated will work well with both mutable and non-mutable types being wrapped. I'm not sure I get how can a wrapper copy without an `equals()` method work though.

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider what options you have.

1. Create your own Container-class with `isUpdated()` operation and use your own workaround.
2. If your map contains just a few elements and you are iterating over the map very frequently compared against put/delete operation. It could be a good choice to use `CopyOnWriteArrayList`
   `CopyOnWriteArrayList<Entry<Integer, Integer>> lookupArray = ...;`
3. The other option is to implement your own `CopyOnWriteMap`

   ```
   public class CopyOnWriteMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V>{

       private volatile Map<K, V> currentMap;

       public V put(K key, V value) {
           synchronized (this) {
               Map<K, V> newOne = new HashMap<K, V>(this.currentMap);
               V val = newOne.put(key, value);
               this.currentMap = newOne; // atomic operation
               return val;
           }
       }

       public V remove(Object key) {
           synchronized (this) {
               Map<K, V> newOne = new HashMap<K, V>(this.currentMap);
               V val = newOne.remove(key);
               this.currentMap = newOne; // atomic operation
               return val;
           }
       }

       [...]
   }
   ```

There is a negative side effect. If you are using copy-on-write Collections your updates will be never lost, but you can see some former deleted entry again.

Worst case: deleted entry will be restored every time if map get copied.